# jQuery Validate with multiples forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two forms without id, I could have more, when I try to validate with JQuery Validation Plugin It is successful but the message is placed always inside first form.

```
<form class="myform" action="http://www.google.com">
    <input type="text" name="mytext"/>
    <button class="mybutton">Send</button>
</form>
<form class="myform" action="http://www.google.com">
    <input type="text" name="mytext"/>
    <button class="mybutton">Send</button>
</form>
```

The JQuery Validation is

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.myform').validate({
                rules: {
                    mytext: 'required'
                },
                messages: {
                    mytext: 'Required field'
                }
            });
            $('.mybutton').click(function () {
                var form = $(this).closest('.myform');
                console.log("Action form is: " + form.attr('action'));
                form.valid();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I press the button, I know the validation is successful because the output is `Action form is: http://stackoverflow.com` when I press the first button, and `Action form is: http://www.google.com` when I press the second button.

Is there any way to place the error in the correct form?

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0w4fdo5/2/)

Comment: Are you not able to add something unique to the form ?

Comment: Yes, I could but I must try to do only with class selector because my client doesn't want many changes. I think the problem is in the JQueryValidation plugin when It searches for the input in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` loop:

```
$('.myform').each(function(){
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            mytext: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            mytext: 'Required field'
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2e9rzdt/)